# Any way to update my separate DAL Models Using Entity Framework for .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext, data-access-layer

When **i am updating my DBContext** with below command..

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MySERVER;Database=SSTEST;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DBContext/DBModels

Then DBContext create in ASP.NET Core Web Application by default. I am using my DAL Separate Class Library and want to update DBContext under **DAL** instead of main project application.

[Find PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc3z6.png)

[Required DBContext Like..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc3z6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to select Default project in the Console where you are running the command

Comment: have you installed the package for the assembly for which you are getting error

Comment: can you share the full assembly name which is not getting loaded

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of how you are running the command.